# Do 2 functions when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button where it will remove the readonly attribute of input and also will show the hidden buttons.

The problem is, I need to click my button 2x so that I can do my 2nd function. My target is, how can I achieve the 1 click button only and it'll do my both functions? Remove readonly and show the hidden button.

Thank you

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rain0221/qfjar0x1/14/

```js
//removing readonly attribute of input
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnEditAbout').click(function() {
    var Aboutfields = document.getElementsByClassName('abt');
    for (var x = 0; x < Aboutfields.length; x++) {
      Aboutfields[x].removeAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
  });

  //showing hidden buttons when edit information is clicked

  var btnEditAbout = document.getElementById('btnEditAbout'),
    Removeemp = document.getElementById('Removeemp');
  Addemp = document.getElementById('Addemp');

  function toggle() {
    if (btnEditAbout.style.display === "block") {
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "none";
      Addemp.style.display = "block";
      Removeemp.style.display = "block";
    } else { // switch back
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "block";
      Addemp.style.display = "none";
      Removeemp.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  btnEditAbout.onclick = toggle;
});
```

```css
#btnEditAbout {
  display: block;
}

#Addemp {
  display: none;
}

#Removeemp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm abt" readonly name="Highschool_school" value="" type="text" placeholder="">
<!-- when this button is clicked, it will remove the readonly of the input type. Additionally, it will show the hidden 2 buttons -->
<button class="btn btn-secondary float-right" style="float:right;" id="btnEditAbout" type="button"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit Information </button>
<!-- hidden 2 buttons -->
<button id="Addemp" type="button">Add Record </button>
<button id="Removeemp" type="button">Remove Record </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot click a hidden button

You CAN use jQuery more than you do

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').on("click", function() {
    const edit = this.id === "btnEditAbout"; // what did we click 
    $("#Addemp").toggleClass('hide',!edit)
    $("#Removeemp").toggleClass('hide',!edit)
    $("#btnCancel").toggleClass('hide',!edit)
    if (edit) $(".abt").removeAttr('readonly');
    else  $(".abt").attr('readonly',true);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm abt" readonly name="Highschool_school" value="" type="text" placeholder="">


<!-- when this button is clicked, it will remove the readonly of the input type. Additionally, it will show the hidden 2 buttons -->
<button class="btn btn-secondary float-right toggle" style="float:right;" id="btnEditAbout" type="button"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit Information </button>


<!-- hidden 2 buttons -->
<button id="Addemp" type="button" class="hide">Add Record </button>
<button id="Removeemp" type="button" class="hide">Remove Record </button>
<button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="hide toggle">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answering, i applied your answer to mine but the result is the 2nd button which is the "remove record" is not appearing whenever i click edit information

http://jsfiddle.net/rain0221/qfjar0x1/15/

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer Please see update. If there is nothing else that SHOWS the edit button, you do not need to toggle. Otherwise show more code

Comment: Wow, i didn't see that missing "#" I'm so disappointed in myself. Thank you so much @mplungjan.

The long codes of mine can be shortened by yours. Wow. A lot of things to learn. Thank you a lot

Comment: I see the huge gap. I didn't know that jquery can be so short and pleasant to see in eye. 

I will definitely study about this. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello May i add this question? I'm sorry. 

How can i add a button where it'll undo my action? 

For example "Cancel" button, it means it'll undo my "Edit information" action.

Comment: It shows the 2 hidden buttons and it'll remove the readonly attribute on my input.

When i press "cancel" button... The input should be on readonly again and the 2 buttons should be hidden.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer See update. I changed it a little. I like to toggle the class to show or hide, second parameter is "is it edit or not"

Comment: Hehe. That would bring me to 141.202 rep ;)))

Comment: You could also wrap the 3 buttons in a span and just toggle that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the `toggle();` inside the click event of your edit button

```js
//removing readonly attribute of input
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnEditAbout').click(function() {
    var Aboutfields = document.getElementsByClassName('abt');
    for (var x = 0; x < Aboutfields.length; x++) {
      Aboutfields[x].removeAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
    toggle(); // call the function here
  });

  //showing hidden buttons when edit information is clicked

  var btnEditAbout = document.getElementById('btnEditAbout'),
    Removeemp = document.getElementById('Removeemp');
  Addemp = document.getElementById('Addemp');

  function toggle() {
    if (btnEditAbout.style.display === "block") {
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "none";
      Addemp.style.display = "block";
      Removeemp.style.display = "block";
    } else { // switch back
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "block";
      Addemp.style.display = "none";
      Removeemp.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  btnEditAbout.onclick = toggle;
});
```

```css
#btnEditAbout {
  display: block;
}

#Addemp {
  display: none;
}

#Removeemp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm abt" readonly name="Highschool_school" value="" type="text" placeholder="">
<!-- when this button is clicked, it will remove the readonly of the input type. Additionally, it will show the hidden 2 buttons -->
<button class="btn btn-secondary float-right" style="float:right;" id="btnEditAbout" type="button"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit Information </button>
<!-- hidden 2 buttons -->
<button id="Addemp" type="button">Add Record </button>
<button id="Removeemp" type="button">Remove Record </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are using onclick event twice. You can combine then into one single event like below.

Also rather than checking `btnEditAbout.style.display` you could check for the `window.getComputedStyle` of same node. This will check the inline style aswell as the css styles.

**Working Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var btnEditAbout = document.getElementById('btnEditAbout');
  var Removeemp = document.getElementById('Removeemp');
  var Addemp = document.getElementById('Addemp');

  function toggle() {
    
    var Aboutfields = document.getElementsByClassName('abt');
    for (var x = 0; x < Aboutfields.length; x++) {
      Aboutfields[x].removeAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
    const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(btnEditAbout);
    if (computedStyle.display === "block") {
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "none";
      Addemp.style.display = "block";
      Removeemp.style.display = "block";
    } else { // switch back
      btnEditAbout.style.display = "block";
      Addemp.style.display = "none";
      Removeemp.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  btnEditAbout.onclick = toggle;
});
```

```css
#btnEditAbout {
  display: block;
}

#Addemp {
  display: none;
}

#Removeemp {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm abt" readonly name="Highschool_school" value="" type="text" placeholder="">
<!-- when this button is clicked, it will remove the readonly of the input type. Additionally, it will show the hidden 2 buttons -->
<button class="btn btn-secondary float-right" style="float:right;" id="btnEditAbout" type="button"><i
    class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit Information </button>
<!-- hidden 2 buttons -->
<button id="Addemp" type="button">Add Record </button>
<button id="Removeemp" type="button">Remove Record </button>
```

Comment: This answer is not improving anything, neither style nor readability. It is still using a mix of DOM less jQuery than before, adding the complexity of `getComputedStyle`  - is toggling but has no way to toggle back so no need to toggle or needs to have a way to toggle back added.